# How to effectively ping SQL databases from SP 2013 per list item?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery

What I'd like to accomplish is to have some script per each custom list line ( in a column ) that will show  an icon green or red or td background color when the db is pinged and connection is verified. Is there away to do this? Jquery or what not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"ping" being an entirely different protocol (and even layer) than HTTP, no, you cannot "ping" using JavaScript. Best you could do is try to access a web endpoint and see if you get a response.